# What film or TV episode had breathing bags in it?

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I remember watching a film on TV that involved astronauts going to a planet, which might have been Mars. It had some sort of life form that were described as "breathing bags". They were attached to cave walls and seemed to breath in and out. I remember it being very creepy and the image has stayed with me all these years. I think it was a movie - but I could be wrong. If it was a movie I probably would have seen it again as these sort of things tend to turn up again with time. I was very young at the time - and quite old now. I saw this in probably the early to mid seventies. So this could be something from the 60s or 50s. I don't think it was something like the Outer Limits or Twilight Zone as I wouldn't have been allowed to see it. But now I think of it - I think it may have been, and I managed to steal a look at it. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure they were breathing?  I keep thinking of the image of the Mud Men emerging from the walls in the original Flash Gordon serials, which were re-run on PBS in the late 1970s.  Either way, is there any way you can provide more?  Was it in color or black and white?  Could it have been animated?  What kind of space ship did they have?  Were they in space suits or could they breath the air?  A lot may seem inconsequential, but I've come back to this a few times along the way and keep wishing there were more details that might trigger my memory.

Comment: That really sounds like the movie The Wizard of Mars (1965), kind of a really weird take on Wizard of Oz except on Mars, really weird Sci Fi movie.

Comment: ^ Just rewatched The Wizard of Mars last night and I was wrong, there is no scene that matches your description.

Comment: Star Trek season 1 episode 29 or 30 called Operation: Annihilate has aliens in them that are attached to walls and ceiling but not in caves, the aliens are definitely what I would call Breathing Bags but it never says that in the show.

Answer (score 3):

Star Trek season 1 episode 29 or 30 called [Operation: Annihilate](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Operation_--_Annihilate!) has aliens in them that are attached to walls and ceiling but not in caves, the aliens are definitely what I would call Breathing Bags but it never says that in the show.

[image: Is this what you remember?]

Comment: IIRC, Those things didn't really breathe, though, so much as quiver and jump around.

Comment: Weren't they supposedly giant nerve cells?